# How to merge a nested object with an empty property in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript, merge

Let's say I have an object created in a test setup function that looks like this (it is actually more complicated, but only showing relevant bits):

```
let original = {
    client: {
        id: 1
    },
    server: {
        id: 2
    },
    app: {
        sections: [
            {
                id: 100,
                items: ['first', 'second']
            },
            {
                id: 200
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to reuse the object in a similar function but with an empty `sections` array. Is there a method where I can override just that part to be empty?

For example:

```
let modified = someMerge(original, {
    app: {
        sections: [
            {
                id: 100,
                items: []
            },
            {
                id: 200
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Such that resulting object is:

```
{
    client: {
        id: 1
    },
    server: {
        id: 2
    },
    app: {
        sections: [
            {
                id: 100,
                items: []        // Now empty
            },
            {
                id: 200
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If I try this using `_.merge`, I believe the resulting array isn't empty.

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way than: `original.app.sections[0].items = []`, since there could be multiple nested keyed properties that I would want to override.

Comment: What's more elegant than a direct assignment? It modifies the object exactly as you wanted. How do you define  _elegant_?

Comment: Well this is one case where only one property needs to be changed. There could be multiple. Something like `_.merge` "recursively merges own and inherited enumerable string keyed properties of source objects into the destination object". But it doesn't let you override with undefined values to already existing keys...

Comment: You might want to get acquainted with the `_.mergeWith()` function then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith) to provide a function that customizes what merging happens.  It sounds like what you want is:

1. when *under* a `sections` key
2. if merging two arrays
3. if the second array is empty, take it in place of the first array

You could right this like so, if I understand correctly:

```js
type Sections = { sections: { id: number, items:string[] }[]  };

function isSections(item: any): 
  item is Sections
{
  return item.sections !== undefined;
}

function sectionsMerger(left: any, right: any) {
  if(_.isArray(left) && _.isArray(right)) {
    if(right.length == 0) {
      return [];
    }
  }

  // otherwise merge like normal
  return undefined;
}


function topMerger(left: any, right: any) {
  if(isSections(left) && isSections(right)) {
    return _.mergeWith(left, right, sectionsMerger);
  }
  
  // perform default merging logic
  return undefined;
}

let result = _.mergeWith(
  original,
  toMerge,
  topMerger
);

console.log(result);
```

I used a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) with `isSections` to make case 1 easier to reason about, but it's not necessary.